# Pass objects in Set to Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Set of Objects which I need to pass from view to Controller.
When I need to do that for a List of Objects, I use the following code:

```
<div th:each="element, elementStat : *{listOfObjects}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{listOfObjects[__${elementStat.index}__].id}"/>
</div>
```

This way I have the object's id available in the Controller. Unfortunately, this does not work for Sets since they cannot be indexed. How would I solve this for Sets?

Comment: I can't image a way to bridging the gap between the concept of binding and Sets. I think the smartest approach is to extend the object (that is bind with th:object at the form tag) with a list of ints, longs, uuids or what ever your indices looks like.

Comment: @Flocke Thanks, I'm also pretty sure by now that I am approaching this problem from the wrong direction. What I ended up with, is to reload the entity from the database. The reason I wanted to pass things back to the controller in the first place was to compare the modified user objects with their old state in the database. So I tried to keep the old state in the session by passing them back and forth. Simply reloading is much easier in this case.